# ngx-charts: select data on bar chart and change color via code

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, ngx-charts

I am using [`ngx-charts`](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts) for the firs time and I am creating a [`ngx-charts-bar-vertical`](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts/examples/bar-charts/vertical-bar-chart) chart.

I have created the chart successfully but I am wondering if it is possible to select one of the bars by the `name` value.

In particular, my data look like:

```
[
  {
    name: '2020-01-01',
    value: 13
  },
  {
    name: '2020-01-02',
    value: 27
  }
]
```

I'd like to know if it is possible to select a specific bar by `name` and change its color to make it more prominent.

The idea is that, because in my app there is a date picker, I'd like to use the selected date to highlight the value for that date in the chart.

I see that the vertical bar chart has several events associated (like select, activate), but I cannot seem to understand if these could be useful for what I need.

Also, if this is relevant, I can use different types of dates in my application, so if strings are not the best, i can easily work with JavaScript `Date` objects if needed (although I don't see any `time`-related option in the vertical bar chart docs, but I see it in the [`line chart`](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts/examples/line-area-charts/line-chart) one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it. I used the `customColors` property of `vertical-bar-chart` to set the color of the bar based on the value of one of its labels.

Basically, what I did was defining a `customColors` property within my chart class ts file, added it in the html as well, and then I can change the color of it based on a value I want.

As my values are dates, I can do something like this:

```
this.getTime().subscribe(time => {
  this.customColors = [
    {
        name: time.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        value: '#ff0000' // RED FOR THIS DATE ONLY
    }
  ];
});
```

In my app, `this.getTime()` gives me the current time from the date picker as `Observable<moment.Moment>`, and I can use this `moment` date object to format the way it is in the chart to "select" my bar and change its color.